# Show image when button is clicked

Tags: java, arrays, function, click, show

I have this div:

```
<div id="flaw">
    <img id='flaw1' src='images\flaw1.png'>
    <img id='flaw2' src='images\flaw2.png'>
    <img id='flaw3' src='images\flaw3.png'>
    <img id='flaw4' src='images\flaw4.png'>
    <img id='flaw5' src='images\flaw5.png'>
    <img id='flaw6' src='images\flaw6.png'>
    <img id='flaw7' src='images\flaw7.png'>
    <img id='flaw8' src='images\flaw8.png'>
    <img id='flaw9' src='images\flaw9.png'>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make 3 buttons. Every time 1 random button should be good. the other 2 bad buttons should make 1 of the images appear. 
If you click the wrong button 9 times, all images will be visible and you would lose the game.

First I tried putting all images in an array, but I kept failing...

Eventually I ended up with this;

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var buttons = $("#buttons img");
    var flaw = $("#flaw img");


    window.onload = function () {

        flaw.hide();

    };

    buttons.on('click', function () {
        $("#flaw1").show();
    })
});
```

All it has to do now is show the first image when someone clicks a button. 
And show the next image when someone clicks it again and again and again. 
Until all 9 images are visible.
But I could figure out how to loop through the images on every click.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: I believe this question is about javascript, not java. If possible, change your tags so javascript people can reach this question.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
    var flaws = $("#flaw img");
    buttons.on('click', function () {
        flaws.each(function(){
            if ( ($(this).is(":hidden") ){
                $(this).show();
                break;
            }
        });
    })
```

For further refernces check

- http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/each/